# What is the difference between int and int64 in Go?

Tags: go

I have a string containing an integer (which has been read from a file).

I'm trying to convert the `string` to an `int` using `strconv.ParseInt()`.  `ParseInt` requires that I provide a bitsize (bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8, int16, int32, and int64).

The integer read from the file is small (i.e. it should fit in a normal int). If I pass a bitsize of 0, however, I get a result of type `int64` (presumably because I'm running on a 64-bit OS).

Why is this happening? How do I just get a normal int? (If someone has a quick primer on when and why I should use the different int types, that would awesome!)

Edit: I can convert the int64 to a normal int using `int([i64_var])`. But I still don't understand why `ParseInt()` is giving me an int64 when I'm requesting a bitsize of 0.

Comment: Use [Atoi](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) for brevity? Also, is your ParseInt function returning an error?

Comment: Okay, now I'm a little confused. If I use Atoi(), it gives me an int, and everything works. I was calling `parseInt(s, 0, 0)`, which should infer base10 (since the string doesn't have a base prefix). However, Atoi is shorthand for calling `parseInt` w/ a base of 10. Why does the base parameter make a difference in the type returned?

Comment: The base parameter determines how the input string is read. A string might look like "123" or "0xBEEFCAKE" or "1011101" or "0677". All of which have a different meaning and yield a different numeric value. A base value of `0` means the code tries to figure this out by itself. But sometimes this is not possible. `11`(decimal) vs `11` (binary) represent entirely different values.

Comment: Okay, I guess what I'm really confused about is the docs. The docs for Atoi say only that it's just a "shorthand for `parseInt(s, 10, 0)`". But why then does Atoi return `int` while `parseInt` return int64?

Comment: Not knowing exactly why, I will assume that `Atoi` was added simply to accommodate people who are more familiar with the C API: `int atoi ( const char * str );`

Comment: Makes sense. @Matt if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it (all the answers have useful info, but your's was the best way to do what I wanted!)

Comment: @IsaacDontjeLindell per your comment you should change the accepted answer to [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492188/1365918)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)
```

`ParseInt` always returns `int64`.

`bitSize` defines the range of values.

> If the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err = ErrRange.

http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt

```
type int int
```

> int is a signed integer type that is at least 32 bits in size. It is a distinct type, however, and not an alias for, say, int32.

http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int

So `int` could be bigger than 32 bit in the future or on some systems like `int` in C.

I guess on some systems `int64` might be faster than `int32` because that system only works with 64-bit integers.

Here is an example of an error when `bitSize` is 8:

http://play.golang.org/p/_osjMqL6Nj

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt("123456", 10, 8)
    fmt.Println(i, err)
}
```

Comment: In practice, Go usually uses `int64` for `int` on an amd64 GOARCH and `int32` for `int` on 32-bit GOARCHes. At least with the default compiler, I'm not sure about gccgo. So "`int` could be bigger than 32 bit..." isn't just speculation, it's actually rather likely since the 64-bit compilation targets are generally considered the main branch in Go.

Comment: "In practice, Go **usually** uses int64 for int on an amd64 [..]" - more precisely, **int always equals the processor bit-size**. So on 64 bit systems, it's 64 bit, on 32bit systems, it's 32 bit. I like to think it's either an alias of int32 or int64 depending on your compile target (even if it is not implemented as an alias, doesn't matter).

Comment: @zupa what is the source/reference for "int always equals the processor bit-size"?

Answer (score 34):

> [Package strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> [func ParseInt](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)
>
> ```
> func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)
> ```
>
> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (2 to 36) and returns
>   the corresponding value i. If base == 0, the base is implied by the
>   string's prefix: base 16 for "0x", base 8 for "0", and base 10
>   otherwise.
>
> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must
>   fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8,
>   int16, int32, and int64.
>
> The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and
>   include err.Num = s. If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err
>   = ErrSyntax; if the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err = ErrRange.

`ParseInt` always returns an `int64` value. Depending on `bitSize`, this value will fit into `int`, `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, or `int64`. If the value cannot be represented by a signed integer of the size given by `bitSize`, then `err.Err = ErrRange`.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> The value of an n-bit integer is n bits wide and represented using
>   two's complement arithmetic.
>
> ```
> int8        the set of all signed  8-bit integers (-128 to 127)
> int16       the set of all signed 16-bit integers (-32768 to 32767)
> int32       the set of all signed 32-bit integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
> int64       the set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
> ```
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint     either 32 or 64 bits
> int      same size as uint
> ```

`int` is either 32 or 64 bits, depending on the implementation. Usually it's 32 bits for 32-bit compilers and 64 bits for 64-bit compilers.

To find out the size of an `int` or `uint`, use `strconv.IntSize`.

> [Package strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> [Constants](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#pkg-constants)
>
> ```
> const IntSize = intSize
> ```
>
> `IntSize` is the size in bits of an `int` or `uint` value.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Compiler, runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize)
}
```

Output:

```
gc amd64 linux
64
```

Answer (score 7):

`strconv.ParseInt` and friends return 64-bit versions to keep the API clean and simple.
Else one would have to create separate versions for each possible return type. Or return `interface{}`, which would then have to go through a type assertion. None of which are ideal.

`int64` is chosen, because it can hold any integer size up to, and including, the supported 64-bits. The bit size you pass into the function, ensures that the value is properly clamped to the correct range. So you can simply do a type conversion on the returned value, to turn it into whatever integer type you require.

As for the difference between `int` and `int64`, this is architecture-dependant. `int` is simply an alias for either a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, depending on the architecture you are compiling for.

For the discerning eye: The returned value is a signed integer. There is a separate `strconv.ParseUint` function for unsigned integers, which returns `uint64` and follows the same reasoning as explained above.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, this is almost correct, except that I don't think `int` is simply an alias - it is in fact a distinct type. http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int

Comment: Indeed. Go doesn't really do type aliasing. Something like `type int int32` is to be treated as a unique and separate type. Notably because it allows new functionality to be defined for the `int` type through the application of new methods.

Answer (score 6):

For your purposes, [`strconv.Atoi()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) would be more convenient I think.

The other answers have been pretty exhaustive about explaining the `int` type, but I think a link to the Go language specification is merited here: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Answer (score 3):

An `int` is the default signed type in go: it takes 32 bits (4 bytes) on a 32-bit machine and 64 bits(8 bytes) on a 64-bit machine.
Reference- [The way to go by Ivo Balbaert](https://sites.google.com/site/thewaytogo2012/)

Answer (score 1):

In Go lang, each type is considered as separate data type which can not be used interchangeably with the base type. For example,

```
type CustomInt64 int64
```

In the above declaration, CustomInt64 and built-in int64 are two separate data types and cannot be used interchangeably.

The same is the case with int, int32, and int64, all of these are separate data types that can't be used interchangeably. Where int32 is 32 its integer type, int64 is 64 bits and **the size of the generic int type is platform dependent. It is 32 bits wide on a 32-bit system and 64-bits wide on a 64-bit system.** So we must be careful and specific while specifying generic data types like int, uint, and float. It may cause a problem somewhere in code and will crash application on a different platform.